# Windows Phone: How to get list of installed applications & install/remove applications remotely

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In Windows Phone I thought it wasn't possible to list the installed applications on the device, however, the company named AirWatch claims their product can do so. http://www.air-watch.com/solutions/windows-phone

Not only listing applications is possible but also installing and removing them remotely, according to AirWatch.

Anyone have any clue how is it done? I have searched the API and it doesn't seem possible since every application lives in its own sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AirWatch is a software for entreprise deployment. It's simply built upon Windows Phone's company hub.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

+1

In addition to KooKiz, Only the solution is MDM (Mobile Device Management) for Developing a Company Hub app. There is Managed API [InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.findpackagesforcurrentpublisher%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) allows you to get all installed application by same Publisher ID on your phone.

Hope it helps