# How to Launch a Nokia Apps using HERE Launchers or Uri Schemes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nokia, here-api, here-launcher

After some research I found two separate links on the NOKIA dev resources website regarding different schemes for using either the HERE Launchers http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/here-launchers-api-reference.html or Uri Schemes http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/wp-uri-schemes-for-location-applications.html to launch NOKIA apps. My first question is, are these limited to only the NOKIA Lumia devices, or can I include these in my app that will be deployed to any WP8 phone? Also, Is there a way to detect, before launching that task, whether the app is actually installed on the user's device? For instance using the HERE launcher option (which seems the most straightforward)

The using declaration

```
using Nokia.Phone.HereLaunchers;
```

And on my click event

```
ExploremapsShowMapTask showmap = new ExploremapsShowMapTask(); 
showmap.ViewPort = new LocationRectangle(new GeoCoordinate(60.35, 24.60), new GeoCoordinate(60.25, 24.80)); 
showmap.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE maps is not limited only for lumia devices (however - it is pretty pricey and I doubt any non-lumia user would purchase those)
you could try and use an API to get list of installed apps and see whether it is installed or not and than decide whether to run the desired task or not

[Windows Phone: How to get list of installed applications & install/remove applications remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386177/windows-phone-how-to-get-list-of-installed-applications-install-remove-applic)

Comment: Seems your link is for the Company style apps, in which case this is not suited for me because I am launching to the entire marketplace for any user. Is there a way to get a list of installed apps or somehow check to see if the launch was successful? Possibly using a try/catch block or some sort of completed event argument? Might you possibly post a sample for reference?

Comment: To note, I dont see documentation stating anything about a completed event that returns a value, so MAYBE a try catch would work although if it errors out not being able to launch the HERE app, how might i elegantly fix my solution to not cancel but return to the calling page.

Comment: the underlying functionality is fire-and-forget type, thus there are no ways on getting any success or return values.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking that if the launcher failed to launch the application, would it just resume the calling application, or crash the calling application? My assumption is to place the launcher in a try catch so that if an error does occur, I can somehow successfully resume the calling application and display a message. Could you offer suggestions on how to do something like this?

Comment: its schema handler lauching, thus no such option available