# Is possible to know which apps were installed to the device?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm writing an app, it can list all apps in user device, is there have a way to know which apps were installed to the phone via wp8.1 public API currently? Can I get the app list?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a program to do this, or just how to find out as a user?

Comment: I'm going to write an app, not for as a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe those two answers: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18386177/2681948) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13617515/2681948) are still actual.

Looking [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx), PackageManager class is available only for desktop applications, not phone:

> Minimum supported phone - None supported

Thought for Enterprise Deployment you can use on Phone [InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.findpackagesforcurrentpublisher.aspx) - as written in first reference.